# Методы операций с комлпексными числами с использованием Hashset

Tags: java, hashset

В университете дали задание:
Реализовать методы сложения, вычитания, умножения и деления объектов. Создать множество (HashSet) размерности n из комплексных координат. Передать его в метод, который выполнит сложение/умножение его элементов.

Реализация методов самих операций у меня есть, но я не могу понять, зачем нужен hashset и как его реализовать в коде. Почитал статьи, но все равно не понял, как применить класс к реализации.

```
import java.lang.Math;

public class Complex {
    double dReal, dImaginary;

    // Конструктор

    public Complex() {}

    public Complex( double dReal, double dImaginary ) {
        this.dReal      = dReal; // Действительное
        this.dImaginary = dImaginary; // Мнимое
    }

    // Конвертация комплексного числа

    public String toString() {
        if (dImaginary >= 0)
            return dReal + "+" +  dImaginary + "i";
        else
            return dReal + "-" + -dImaginary + "i";
    }


    // ================================================================  
    // Операции над комплексными числами


    // cA + cB
    public Complex Add(Complex cB ) {
        Complex sum = new Complex();

        sum.dReal      = dReal      + cB.dReal;
        sum.dImaginary = dImaginary + cB.dImaginary;

        return (sum);
    }

    // cA * cB

    public Complex Mult( Complex cB ) {
        Complex multi = new Complex();

        multi.dReal      = dReal*cB.dReal      - dImaginary*cB.dImaginary;
        multi.dImaginary = dImaginary*cB.dReal + dReal*cB.dImaginary;

        return (multi);
    }

    // cA - cB
    public Complex Sub( Complex cB ) {
        Complex subs = new Complex();

        subs.dReal      = dReal      - cB.dReal;
        subs.dImaginary = dImaginary - cB.dImaginary;

        return (subs);
    }



    // cA / cB

    public Complex Div( Complex cB ) {
        Complex div = new Complex();
        double dR, dDen;

        if(Math.abs( cB.dReal ) >= Math.abs( cB.dImaginary )) {
            dR   = cB.dImaginary/cB.dReal;
            dDen = cB.dReal + dR*cB.dImaginary;
            div.dReal      = (dReal      + dR*dImaginary)/dDen;
            div.dImaginary = (dImaginary - dR*dReal)/dDen;
        } else {
            dR   = cB.dReal/cB.dImaginary;
            dDen = cB.dImaginary + dR*cB.dReal;
            div.dReal      = (dR*dReal      + dImaginary)/dDen;
            div.dImaginary = (dR*dImaginary - dReal)/dDen;
        }

        return (div);
    }
    // ================================================================  


   
    public static void main (String args[]) {

        // Ввод и вывод в консоль двух комплексных чисел

        Complex cA = new Complex( 1.0, 2.0 );
        Complex cB = new Complex( 3.0, 4.0 );

        System.out.println("cA = " + cA.toString() );
        System.out.println("cB = " + cB.toString() );

        // Вывод операций

        Complex cAdd = cA.Add(cB);
        System.out.println("Complex   cA + cB = " + cAdd.toString() );
        Complex cSub = cA.Sub(cB);
        System.out.println("Complex   cA - cB = " + cSub.toString() );
        Complex cDiv = cA.Mult(cB);
        System.out.println("Complex   cA * cB = " + cDiv.toString() );
        Complex cMult = cA.Div(cB);
        System.out.println("Complex   cA / cB = " + cMult.toString() );

    }
}
```

Comment: я так понял hashSet нужен только чтобы сложить туда эти комплексные числа

Answer (score 0):

Если я правильно понял, вам надо сложить/вычесть/умножить/разделить все числа внутри одного множества. Тогда это будет выглядеть так:

```
public static Complex Add(HashSet<Complex> set) {
    Complex result = null;
    for (Complex c : set) 
        if (result == null)
            result = c;
        else
            result = result.Add(c);
    
    return result;
}

public static Complex Sub(HashSet<Complex> set) {
    Complex result = null;
    for (Complex c : set)
        if (result == null)
            result = c;
        else
            result = result.Sub(c);
    return result;
}

public static Complex Mul(HashSet<Complex> set) {
    Complex result = null;
    for (Complex c : set)
        if (result == null)
            result = c;
        else
            result = result.Mult(c);
    return result;
}

public static Complex Div(HashSet<Complex> set) {
    Complex result = null;
    for (Complex c : set)
        if (result == null)
            result = c;
        else
            result = result.Div(c);
    return result;
}
```

Вычитание и деление выполняются из первого элемента, а остальные операции и так коммутативны

Comment: Спасибо за помощь. Надеюсь это решает задачу.